# Two .axd handlers, one is working and the other one returns 404

Tags: asp.net, web-config, handler, httphandler, axd

I have 2 custom .axd handlers in my project.
Both defined in web.config under httpHandlers and handlers:

httpHandlers:

```
    <add verb="GET" path="ShowImage.axd" validate="false" type="ImageServer.StreamImage, ImageServer"/>

  <add verb="GET,POST" path="Upload.axd" validate="false" type="UploadFileServer.UploadFile, UploadFileServer"/>
```

handlers:

```
    <add name="ImageServer" preCondition="integratedMode" path="ShowImage.axd" verb="GET" type="ImageServer.StreamImage, ImageServer"/>
  <add name="UploadFileServer" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Upload.axd" verb="GET,POST" type="UploadFileServer.UploadFile, UploadFileServer"/>
```

when I call ShowImage.axd everything is working fine.

The request in fiddler looks like:

GET /WebApp/ShowImage.axd?Bla=x HTTP/1.1

when I call Upload.axd, I get 404.

The request in fiddler looks like:

POST /WebApp/Upload.axd HTTP/1.1

Both .dll's are in the Bin folder.

why?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the code how you are calling the Upload handler.
Till then try making your upload hander use only "POST" verb and see if it works.

```
<add verb="POST" path="Upload.axd" validate="false" type="UploadFileServer.UploadFile, UploadFileServer"/>
```

Comment: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "Upload.axd", true);
 xhr.save(fd);

Comment: As I mentioned,accepting only "POST" verb is not working?Did you try?

Comment: I tried. I stopped getting 404, I am not sure if because of using only POST or because I added to the handler definition resourceType="Unspecified" for IIS7. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: My mistake. Still returns 404

Comment: If I understood correctly, your upload handler is for file upload.I am afraid that you will be able to upload file with that simple xmlHttpRequest unless you play around by adding IFrame.Try using jquery form plugin for ajaxly uploading files. Your server side configuration looks ok.Following is the jquery form plugin url http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: I use jquery form like you said, but still get 404. It works fine on IE10, chrome, firefox... but returns 404 using IE 8/9.